# Loop iterates only once using tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to iterate over a list of lists however I noticed that only the first item was being printed out. I then tried to simply print out all integers from 1 -> 10 and noticed that only 0 was being printed. If I pressed the 'Send email' button again, which calls the parse answers command, then all the rest of integers show up (eg. 1 -> 9). This also happens if I close my GUI. How can I stop it from freezing.

```
def parse_answers():
    if(not FILE_PATH):
        return

    data = pd.read_excel(FILE_PATH)

    rows = data.to_numpy()
    
    for i in range(0, 10, 1):
        print(i)


def email_submission(root, canvas):
    button = tk.Button(
        text='Send email',
        command = lambda: parse_answers()
    )

    canvas.create_window(50, 200, window=button)
```

EXAMPLE:

`Press 'Send Email' button`

output:

```
0
```

`Press 'Send Email' button again`

output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
0
```

Essentially, the loop freezes after the first iteration but continues after another command is given.

Comment: `lambda: parse_answers()` is more neatly written as `parse_answers`.

Comment: Anyway, `print` shouldn't generally be used in a GUI application except for debugging (and there are probably better tools even then).

Comment: I am not using print for that, I was just using for testing. Like if I am reading the correct values of the data, but the loop hangs up which was my concern :(

Comment: The for loop in the posted code should not freeze the application.

Comment: It does not freeze the application, it freezes the loop

Comment: It should not freeze the loop as well based on your posted code.